# Referring something which is not the last item, but one before the last one

Tags: single-word-requests

what is the true phrase to refer something informally and formally which is not the last one, but one before the last?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a phrase, but the name for an item which is next to last (in a list, or in an order) is *penultimate*. And although you didn't ask, the name for the item which is next to the next to the last is *antepenultimate*.

Comment: thanks. it seams a little formal. does it have any more casual equal?

Comment: The more casusal equivalent is "next to last", according to Wiktionary. As danph notes, there is a difference between US and UK usage. In US, penultimate usually means "next to last"; in UK, penultimate usually means "second to last".

Answer (score 11):

More casual than *penultimate* is *second last*, *second to last*, or *second-to-last*.

I did some queries in the [COCA and BNC](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) corpora, and it seems that *second last* is the more common form in British English. *Second to last* / *second-to-last* are more common in American English.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is 'last but one' (for penultimate), and 'last but two' (for antepenultimate). Casually, I would say 'second last' (I speak a kind of British English), so it confirms what dangph said. I am also told Americans say 'the next to last'.

Answer (score 0):

Casually, second-last can be used.

Comment: This answer has already been suggested.